# Why is my getter from store in App.vue class undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-class-components

I am building an electron app using vue, vuex and vuex-typescript. So I have the following code for my store using vuex-typescript:

```
export const dispaVuex = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    dispatch: new Dispatcher(appState),
  },

  getters: {
    getFTime(state: DispatchState): boolean {
      return state.dispatch.fistTime;
    },
  },
};

const {read} = getStoreAccessors<DispatchState, RootState>("Test");

export const readFtime = read(dispaVuex.getters.getFTime);
```

After adding the store to my vue instance I try and access the firstTime variable in my App.vue like this:

```
@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  // fTime: boolean;
  get fTime(): boolean {
    return readFtime(this.$store);
  }
}
```

When looking at the debugger, everything in the store is initialized perfectly but my App instance has fTime as undefined.

Why would this be the case? Is there something I am not getting about the order of how things are made?

PS. firstTime is a member of the class Dispatcher

Comment: Did you initialize state in your Vue root component? readFtime() is getter function, maybe do you should pass getters functions in component before using? For example see MapGetters helper https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Comment: change `return readFtime(this.$store);` to `return this.$store.getters.getFTime;` then try again

Comment: @Sergey I did import the dispVuex object along with the RootState and initialized the store like this: 
`const store = new Vuex.Store<RootState>({
  modules: {
    dispaVuex,
  },
});`
Then did this in my to init my Vue instance:
`new Vue({
  components: { App },
  store,
  template: "<App/>",
}).$mount("#app");`

Comment: @Sphinx I tried doing that but it didn't work, I know what you are trying to say but I think it is different for me since I'm using vuex-typescript. This is the example I am following: https://github.com/DevoidCoding/TodoMVC-Vue-TypeScript/tree/master/vuex-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking closely at the example given in the vuex-typescript readme, I noticed that I was passing the wrong namespace when calling the function `getStoreAccessors`.

Using `dispaVuex` instead of `Test` like this fixed the problem:

```
const {read} = getStoreAccessors<DispatchState, RootState>("dispaVuex");
```